# How do I prevent my Android from vibrating once when I turn on vibrate mode out of Digital Wellbeing's Bedtime mode?

Tags: vibration, digital-wellbeing

I use [Digital Wellbeing's Bedtime mode](https://blog.google/outreach-initiatives/digital-wellbeing/improve-your-sleep/) to automatically turn my phone on silent for the night and back on vibrate for the day. In the morning, when it automatically turns on the vibrate mode at 7 am, it vibrates once. This annoyingly sometimes wakes me up. Consequently, I want to prevent my Android from vibrating once when I turn on vibrate mode.

Tried:

1. I went to Settings > Sounds and vibration > Vibrate. Changing the Vibration intensity for calls to zero did the trick. Now my phone no longer vibrates when turned to vibrate. But it also doesn't vibrate if I get a call which is a bigger problem than what it solved.
2. I turned the sleep mode settings to a later point. Better, but possibly a problem if I missed an early call.

How do I just disable the vibration when the vibrate mode is turned on, but keep all other vibrations intact?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. I never use Digital Wellbeing's Bedtime mode, but I only use scheduled DnD instead, which AFAIR doesn't vibrate when it goes off. Is that an acceptable alternative?

Comment: I use the Bedtime mode also to grayscale my phone. I think this wouldn't be available in DnD?

Comment: You're right. If that's the case, then sorry, I don't have any idea...